# I have data in an array and am looking to strip out one part of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have an output of an array number_list = [1, 4]. What
I have overwrites my array. Any Ideas? Thanks

```
data = [{"key":"50", "name": "James", "$": "1"},
        {"key":"20", "name": "George", "$": "4"}]

$.each(data, function(){  
    number = this.$  
    var number_list = number.push(this.$)  
})
```

Comment: To fix your code, use `var number_list = [];` before the $.each, then do `number_list.push(this.$);` inside. (your var is local to the function and will be recreated each time and not exist outside. Also, you're doing `this.$.push(this.$)`, which doesn't make sense)

Comment: "*strip out*" - generally means remove - so you'd be left with `{key:50,name:james}` - is that what you wanted?  or did you mean *extract*?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
const data = [{"key":"50", "name": "James", "$": "1"},
              {"key":"20", "name": "George", "$": "4"}]

const number_list = data.map(i => i.$);
```